# Adding a Menu Button into VS2010 TFS Query Result or Work Item bar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs-workitem

I am trying to add button(s) to the Visual Studio / TFS2010 Work Item query results menu bar and also to the menu bar shown for individual Work Items (see image below) - is that actually customizable & doable and if so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question (as the one by NGM was helpful but it did not directly answer it.) - no it is not possible as the Work Item & Query Windows inside Visual Studio, particularly their toolbars, are not callable as commands in a VS (SDK) sense.

Basically they are merely WinForms controls (well, were for VS2010, I think this has changed to WPF in VS2013 by now) placed inside a WinForms form hosted inside a VS ToolWindow. The toolbars I outlined above cannot be customised via the VS SDK.

This may have changed in VS2012 or VS2013, but for VS2010 there was/is no way to add custom items into the two toolbars I asked for back then.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at this post:

[TFS 2010 - Adding a menu item to the Completed Builds context menu in the Build Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2011/04/08/tfs-2010-adding-a-menu-item-to-the-completed-builds-context-menu-in-the-build-explorer.aspx)

It discusses the steps you need to take to add menu items to context menus.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.