# Visual Studio Extensibility - Add Button to TFS Work Item Bar

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, vsx, vs-extensibility, workitem

i try to add a button to the toolbar of a tfs work item...but i can't find the menu guidid for the bar.

vsct powertoys downloadlink is dead and with EnableVSIPLogging setting in registry the bar does not deliver a id for the menu.

any ideas or somebody knows the ids?

i successfully placed my action into the contextmenu of the workitem (guid: {2DC8D6BB-916C-4B80-9C52-FD8FC371ACC2} and 0x0206 for Contextmenu)...
but toolbar-button in the workitem would be nicer :)

Thanks

Comment: another user with same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608407/adding-a-menu-button-into-vs2010-tfs-query-result-or-work-item-bar

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should be 0x100 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/06/24/extending-work-item-tracking-context-menus.aspx

Comment: this number i've already tried... but 0x0100 is only the toolbar "Work Item Tracking" but not the Toolbar in the Work Item Editor :/